# How do i get the selected Item in a Tabmenu from Primeng

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular5

i have a simple MenuItem Array that i use to fill the Tabmenu component from primeng. This looks something like this:

.ts file:

```
items = MenuItem[];
activeItem = MenuItem;

//constructor etc...

ngOnInit() {

    this.items = [
                {label: 'Homework', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'},
                {label: 'Movies', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'},
                {label: 'Games', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'},
                {label: 'Pictures', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'}
            ];
this.activeItem = this.items[2]
}
```

.html file:

```
<p-tabMenu [model]="items" [activeItem]="activeItem"></p-tabMenu>
```

I know i can set the Active item of the `tabmenu` with the help of the activeItem like so:

```
this.activeItem = this.items[2]
```

My question now is can i somehow retrieve the activeItem on click?  e.g.

```
<p-tabMenu [model]="items" [activeItem]="activeItem" (click)="getActiveItem(...)"></p-tabMenu>
```

getActiveItem Method:

```
getActiveItem(activeItem: MenuItem){
    this.activeItem = activeItem;
    console.log(activeItem);
    return this.activeItem;
  }
```

P.S a link to the TabMenu from Primeng. [CLICK](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabmenu)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to use [**`command`**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel) since tabs are part of the MenuModel API

> The function to invoke when an item is clicked is defined using the
>   **command** property.

```
this.items = [
   ...
  {label: 'Pictures', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o', command: (event) => {
    //event.originalEvent: Browser event
    //event.item: menuitem metadata
  }}
];
```

Answer (score 5):

I just resolved it by creating a variable in the template refered to the menu, and then pass it to a function, inside the function you get the object with the active tab.

```
<p-tabMenu #tab [model]="items" (click)="activateMenu(tab)"></p-tabMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but may need a solution.
THe simplest way is to use templating.
First you declare the items:

```
this.items = [
  {label: 'Homework', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'},
  {label: 'Movies', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'},
  {label: 'Games', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'},
  {label: 'Pictures', icon: 'fa-file-pdf-o'}
];
```

Now in your HTML:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item let-i="index">
  <div (click)="onTabItemClick(i)">
    <span>
      <i class="{{ item.icon }}"></i>
    </span>
    {{ item.label }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Finally I implemented a basic method:

```
onTabItemClick(i: number) {
  console.log(this.items[i])
}
```

On click we retrieve the item by its index.

Answer (score 0):

simply pass it as a parameter to the function

```
(click)="getActiveItem(activeItem)"
```

Comment: i tried that unfortunatly it returns undefined. I edit my question with my method